# How to calculate all possible results in a 4x3 array?

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net

assume that the array looks like this.

```
var res = [2,4,1,6,
           1,1,2,8,
           5,6,7,1];
```

all possible four quadrants combinations of this array are 81.

in this example we have only one combination on index : 4,5,2,11 which is four 1.

my question is how to calculate them.

thanks.

Comment: Do you want your answer in js, c# or in vb.net?

Comment: I dont have problem but i prefer in vb or js.

Comment: This isn't a "please write some code for me" forum. Please choose a language, attempt an implementation yourself, and if you have a problem coming up with a working implementation, ask a question here that includes your attempt.

Comment: sorry but i am new here and i dont know exactly how do i have to post my question.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we prefer questions that have a bit of research/attempts behind them in order to avoid _too_ long/broad answers and to be able to provide as accurate answers as possible. Please take a moment to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about how this site works. A good read is also [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Thank you, and good luck!

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am going to read the tour after i end up with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to find every subset of length exactly 4 which contains all the same value? If so, you can do this in N^2 time with the following naive algorithm:

```
let quadrants = [];
res.forEach(checkElement => {
    let possibility = [];
    res.forEach((element, index) => {
      if (element === checkElement) {
          possibility.push(index);
      }
    });
    if (possibility.length === 4) {
      quadrants.push(possibility);
    }
});
```

If you want to account for the possibility of the original array having more than 4 of the same number and include *all* subset quadrants, you'll need to change the length check to `>=4` and add one more step at the end of this: calculate the power set of all listed quadrants with length greater than 4, filter out the ones that aren't length 4, and then concatenate those to the quadrants array. (You'll want to remove each quadrant with length >4 from the quadrants array before calculating its power set, so it won't be in the final result.)

If you do that, you may be able to optimize the last step by only calculating the subsets of length 4 of the longer quadrants; try using this as a guide for that if you need it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-subsets-given-size-set/

Comment: This code helps me too much but is not exactly what i want. But it helps me to write my own code. thank you very much.